# Too many authors in author field

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, author-number

My problem: I have a very long list of authors for a few papers - apparently bibtex can´t handle that. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Dehant2012,
    Author = {Veronique Dehant and Bruce Banerdt and Philippe Lognonn{\'e} and
Matthias Grott and Sami Asmar and Jens Biele and Doris Breuer and Fran{\c c}ois
Forget and Ralf Jaumann and Catherine Johnson and Martin Knapmeyer and Benoit
Langlais and Le Feuvre, Mathieu and David Mimoun and Antoine Mocquet and Peter Read
and Attilio Rivoldini and Oliver Romberg and Gerald Schubert and Sue Smrekar and
Tilman Spohn and Paolo Tortora and Stephan Ulamec and Susanne Vennerstr{\o}m},
    Journal = {Planetary and Space Science},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {123 - 145},
    Title = {Future {Mars} geophysical observatories for understanding its internal
             structure, rotation, and evolution},
    Volume = {68},
    Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{newapa}
\begin{document}
\cite{Dehant2012}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

How can I still print the whole list in the bibliography in the end?
At the moment I just get an error and a "?" every time I cite this paper within my text and nothing in the bibliography ...

Comment: BibTeX can handle it; it's the `newapa` style that can't.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Note that BibTeX can only handle ASCII characters, it seems you are using Unicode characters in your `bib` file. What output do you get from the BibTeX run (see also the `blg` file for that)?

Comment: As @egreg says, it's `newapa.bst` that is the problem. Try using the `apalike` bibliography style instead. I've edited your question to create a minimal example.

Comment: The `newapa` bibliography style and the associated LaTeX package `newapa.sty` appear to have been written for LaTeX2.09 and do not appear to have been updated meaningfully in order to work with LaTeX2e (which has been more or less the "standard" version of LaTeX for about twenty years...) As such, `newapa`'s implementation of the APA's citation and referencing guidelines is almost surely woefully out of date by now. The style file `apalike.bst` isn't much newer, by the way. If you need to create APA-style citations and references, do look into one of the newer APA-based files out there.

Comment: Each author should be specified "Surname, First Names".

Comment: @Kathi: did the suggestion of egreg solve your problem?